# Как вставить в число из 4 цифр точку после второй цифры

Tags: php

Мне в скрипт приходит два вида данных: число с тремя цифрами или число с четырьмя цифрами. Как сделать с тремя цифрами я нашел в ПС, а вот с четырьмя не получается :(

С тремя цифрами:

```
$cifry = 352;
(float) preg_replace('~^(\d)([\d]+)~', '\\1.\\2', $cifry);
```

Код выше ставит точку после первой цифры, на выходе - 3.52

А как мне поставить точку после второй цифры если цифры четыре? Т.е. из 2523, сделать 25.23

Comment: Перевести число в строку. Выделить из строки первые два символа, оставшиеся два символа. Склеить их с точкой. И главное - никаких regexp'ов!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$cifry = 352;
echo $cifry / 100; 

echo "\n";

$cifry = 2523;
echo $cifry / 100;
```

Comment: во блин :))) всё гениальное просто. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

```
$cifry = 323423452;
(float) preg_replace("~(\d{2})$~", ".$1", $cifry);
```

Comment: Благодарю! Ваш вариант тоже работает.